# Microsoft UCMA 4.0 API QuickStart App for skype

Tags: visual-studio, skype-for-business, ucma

i'm using Microsoft UCMA 4.0 API QuickStart App AudioVideo Recorder for Skype for Business. When i call user from inside organization, i can contact and record voice.
We have federation with external skype users. When i try to call external sip name.surname(gmail.com)@msn.com i'm getting exeption:

```
An exception of type 'Microsoft.Rtc.Signaling.RegisterException' occurred in Microsoft.Rtc.Collaboration.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The endpoint was unable to register. See the ErrorCode for specific reason.
```

Here is the procedure:

```
   private void EndEndpointEstablish(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        LocalEndpoint currentEndpoint = ar.AsyncState as LocalEndpoint;
        try
        {
            currentEndpoint.EndEstablish(ar);
        }
        catch (AuthenticationException authEx)
        {
            // AuthenticationException will be thrown when the credentials are invalid.
            Console.WriteLine(authEx.Message);
            throw;
        }
        catch (ConnectionFailureException connFailEx)
        {
            // ConnectionFailureException will be thrown when the endpoint cannot connect to the server, or the credentials are invalid.
            Console.WriteLine(connFailEx.Message);
            throw;
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException iOpEx)
        {
            // InvalidOperationException will be thrown when the endpoint is not in a valid state to connect. To connect, the platform must be started and the Endpoint Idle.
            Console.WriteLine(iOpEx.Message);
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            // Again, just for sync. reasons.
            _endpointInitCompletedEvent.Set();
        }
    }
```

How can we reach external users?

After few hours tried second time to call inside user and it is not working. Now getting message:

```
An exception of type 'Microsoft.Rtc.Signaling.AuthenticationException' occurred in RecorderSample.exe but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Not authorized to perform the requested operation, request is refused
```

Why i'm not authorized suddenly?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting confused.

UCMA applications create and service sip endpoints.  A sip endpoint is like a "phone" in that it can make and receive audio / video calls, IMs, etc.

There are two types of endpoints a UCMA application can create:

- [UserEndpoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.rtc.collaboration.userendpoint_di_3_uc_ocs14mreflyncuc3cr.aspx)
- [ApplicationEndpoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.rtc.collaboration.applicationendpoint_di_3_uc_ocs14mreflyncuc3cr.aspx)

Both types of endpoints are pre-defined types of users in Lync.

Sip endpoints need to register with the sip registrar (Lync Front End) which is like pluging a phone into the wall. It's says I'm here, if you get any calls for 'X' send them my way.

So you have done is try to "Register" a sip endpoint that is "name.surname(gmail.com)@msn.com" with your local Lync Front End.  This is illegal, which is why you are getting the "Microsoft.Rtc.Signaling.RegisterException" errors.

What you may want to do is register a "local" Lync user and then "dial" the federated account OR get the federated account to dial you.